# Django: Total birthdays each day for the next 30 days

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got a model similar to this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    birthday = DateTimeField() # their next birthday
```

I would like to get a list of the total birthdays for each day for the next 30 days. So for example, the list would look like this:

```
[[9, 0], [10, 3], [11, 1], [12, 1], [13, 5], ... #30 entries in list
```

Each list entry in the list is a date number followed by the number of birthdays on that day. So for example on the 9th of May there are 0 birthdays.

**UPDATES**

My db is sqlite3 - will be moving to postgres in the future.

Comment: Hang on - is the birthday field their birthday in *this* year, or their actual date of birth?

Comment: Yes it will be their birthday in this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get the list of days and birthday count this way:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta    
today = date.today()
thirty_days = today + timedelta(days=30)

# get everyone with a birthday
people = Person.objects.filter(birthday__range=[today, thirty_days])

birthday_counts = []
for date in [today + timedelta(x) for x in range(30)]:
    # use filter to get only birthdays on given date's day, use len to get total
    birthdays = [date.day, len(filter(lambda x: x.birthday.day == date.day, people))]
    birthday_counts.append(birthdays)
```

Comment: Thanks, although using the `annotate` approach to combine the count with the date is better imo. You should probably use [Daniel Roseman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936966/django-total-birthdays-each-day-for-the-next-30-days/5937638#5937638) instead

Comment: But as Daniel says, his method won't work for a DateTime, which is what I have.

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.db.models import Count
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
thirty_days = today + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
birthdays = dict(Person.objects.filter(
                    birthday__range=[today, thirty_days]
                 ).values_list('birthday').annotate(Count('birthday')))


for day in range(30):
    date = today + datetime.timedelta(day)
    print "[%s, %s]" % (date, birthdays.get(date, 0))
```

Comment: Using the [range](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) field lookup is definitely the way to go.

Comment: But wouldn't you want to avoid `aggregate`? The last part wouldn't work.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - it all works up to the aggregate(Count('birthday') When I add this it just returns {}. Before adding that I get the expected objects.

Comment: Because aggregate would return a dict of only Count('birthday')

Comment: @zeekay @ErnieP aargh, should be `annotate`. Thanks guys.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't even think of annotate!

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I get a separate entry for each birthday with a count of 1 for each entry. I guess that's because birthday is a DateTime rather than Date (each birthday has a different time even if same date)?

Comment: @ErnieP, yes I didn't notice you were using DateTime. If you do need to store the time for whatever reason, my solution will not work.

Comment: I know it's a bit late to this party, but now you could cast the birthday DateTime to Date, and annotate that along with the count. Something like in the following comment:

Comment: birthdays = dict(Person.objects.filter(birthday__range=[today, thirty_days]).annotate(birthday_date=Cast('birthday', DateField())).annotate(birthday_count=Count('birthday_date'))).values_list('birthday_date', 'birthday_count')

Answer (score 0):

Something like this --

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    @staticmethod
    def upcoming_birthdays(days=30):
        today = date.today()
        where = 'DATE_ADD(birthday, INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday)) YEAR) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL %S DAY)'
        birthdays = Person.objects.extra(where=where, params=[days]).values_list('birthday', flat=True)
        data = []
        for offset in range(0, days):
            i = 0
            d = today + timedelta(days=offset)
            for b in birthdays:
                if b.day == d.day and b.month == d.month:
                    i += 1
            data.append((d.day, i))
        return data

print Person.upcoming_birthdays()
```

Comment: I guess you don't need that custom SQL. Also functions that reference multiple objects are better on the Manager than in the Model

Answer (score 0):

(Queryset of people with a birthday in the next X days)
Found cool solution for this!
For me it works!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import operator

from django.db.models import Q

def birthdays_within(days):

    now = datetime.now()
    then = now + timedelta(days)

    # Build the list of month/day tuples.
    monthdays = [(now.month, now.day)]
    while now <= then:
        monthdays.append((now.month, now.day))
        now += timedelta(days=1)

    # Tranform each into queryset keyword args.
    monthdays = (dict(zip(("birthday__month", "birthday__day"), t)) 
                 for t in monthdays)


    # Compose the djano.db.models.Q objects together for a single query.
    query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**d) for d in monthdays))

    # Run the query.
    return Person.objects.filter(query)
```

But it get a list of persons that have a birthday in date range. You should change a bit.