# Queryset of people with a birthday in the next X days

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-queryset

how do i get queryset of people with a birthday in the next X days? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936966/django-total-birthdays-each-day-for-the-next-30-days) answer, but it does not suit me, because gets people only with current year of birth.

Comment: Don't know Django, but wouldn't you just look for the equivalent of `birthday <= (today + X days)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming a model like this--

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    birthday = models.DateTimeField() # their next birthday
```

The next step would be to create a query filtering out any records with birthdays having a month and day in between (now.month, now.day) and (then.month, then.day). You can actually access the month and day attributes of the datetime object using the queryset API by passing Person.objects.filter a keyword argument like this: "birthday__month." I tried this with an actual queryset API method like "birthday__month__gte" and it failed though. So I would suggest simply generating a literal list of month/day tuples representing each (month, day) in the date range you want records for, then compose them all into a query with django.db.models.Q, like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import operator

from django.db.models import Q

def birthdays_within(days):

    now = datetime.now()
    then = now + timedelta(days)

    # Build the list of month/day tuples.
    monthdays = [(now.month, now.day)]
    while now <= then:
        monthdays.append((now.month, now.day))
        now += timedelta(days=1)

    # Tranform each into queryset keyword args.
    monthdays = (dict(zip(("birthday__month", "birthday__day"), t)) 
                 for t in monthdays)


    # Compose the djano.db.models.Q objects together for a single query.
    query = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**d) for d in monthdays))

    # Run the query.
    return Person.objects.filter(query)
```

After debugging, this should return a queryset with each person who has a birthday with month and day equal to any of the months or days in the specified list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks, I think this solution is most correct of all submitted so far.

Comment: The only thing I would change is replace `datetime.now()` with `timezone.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's datetime field do something like this (using future_date from dimosaur answer):

```
Profile.objects.get(
    Q(birthday__lte=future_date),
    Q(birthday__gte=datetime.date.today())
)
```

Comment: This gets people only with current year of birth.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways without using custom queries, both with "problems"

1) Not efficient as it does 1 query per day

```
start = datetime.date.today()
max_days = 14
days = [ start + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in xrange(0, max_days) ]

birthdays = []
for d in days:
    for p in Profile.objects.filter(birthday__month=d.month, birthday__day=d.day):
        birthdays.append(p)

print birthdays
```

2) Single query, but requires a model change. You would need to add bday_month and bday_day integer fields. These can obviously be populated automatically from the real date.

The limitation of this example is that you can only check against 2 months, start month and the end month. Setting 29 days you could jump over february, showing only Jan 31 and Mar 1.

```
from django.db.models import Q    
start = datetime.date.today()
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days=14)

print Profile.objects.filter(
    Q(bday_month=start.month) & Q(bday_day__gte=start.day) | 
    Q(bday_month=end.month) & Q(bday_day__lte=end.day)
)
```

Comment: Check out django.db.models.Q, which you can use to compose numerous query parameters together into a single query. You first solution would work with a single query if you "or"ed the multiple constraints together with Q as in my answers.

Answer (score 0):

If X is a constant that you know:

```
import datetime
future_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=X)
Profile.objects.filter(
    birth_date__month=future_date.month,
    birth_date__day=future_date.day
)
```

Something like that.

Comment: This will result in just one day, i need a range between today and the day X.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do it in a really silly way, but seems it works:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Q

x = 5
q_args = ''

for d in range(x):
    future_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=d)
    q_args += 'Q(birth_date__month=%d, birth_date__day=%d)%s' % (
        future_date.month,
        future_date.day,
        ' | ' if d < x - 1 else ''
    )

people = People.objects.filter(eval(q_args))
```

Comment: i suppose it can turn to expensive database query :D

Answer (score 0):

I was unsatisfied with all replies here. They are all a variant on "check one date/year by one in a range...", making a long, ugly queries. Here is a simple solution, if one is willing to denormalize a bit:

Change your model so instead of just `datetime birthdate(yyyy, mm, dd)` holding the real date you add a `datetime birthday(DUMMY_YEAR, mm, dd)` column. So every person in your DB will have saved its real birth date, and then a another birth date with a fixed year, shared with everyone else. Don't show this second field to users, though, and don't allow them to edit it.

Once you edited your model, make sure the `birthdate` and `birthday` are always connected by extending `models.Model` save method in your class:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.birthday = datetime.date(BIRTHDAY_YEAR, 
         self.birthdate.month, self.birthdate.day)
    super(YOUR_CLASS, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And once you ensured that whenever a date is saved as birthdate, the birthday is updated too, you can filter it with just `birthday__gte`/`birthday__lte`. See an excerpt from my admin filter, where I take care of a year boundary:

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    if self.value() == 'today':
        # if we are looking for just today, it is simple
        return queryset.filter(birthday = datetime.date(
                BIRTHDAY_YEAR, now().month, now().day
            ))

    if self.value() == 'week':
        # However, if we are looking for next few days,
        # we have to bear in mind what happens on the eve
        # of a new year. So if the interval we are looking at
        # is going over the new year, break the search into
        # two with an OR.

        future_date = (now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)).date()
        if (now().year == future_date.year):
            return queryset.filter(
                    Q(birthday__gte = datetime.date(
                        BIRTHDAY_YEAR, now().month, now().day
                    )) &
                    Q(birthday__lte = datetime.date(
                        BIRTHDAY_YEAR,
                        future_date.month,
                        future_date.day)
                    )
                )
        else:
            return queryset.filter(
                    # end of the old year
                    Q(birthday__gte = datetime.date(
                        BIRTHDAY_YEAR, now().month, now().day
                    )) &
                    Q(birthday__lte = datetime.date(BIRTHDAY_YEAR,12, 31)) |
                    # beginning of the new year
                    Q(birthday__gte = datetime.date(BIRTHDAY_YEAR, 1, 1)) &
                    Q(birthday__lte = datetime.date(BIRTHDAY_YEAR,
                        future_date.month,
                        future_date.day)
                    )
                )
```

In case you wonder what the `Q()` is, look on [Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)